# ReactJS - Condicional em um atributo HTML

Tags: javascript, html, react

Estou tentando fazer uma função que atribua um número limitado de casas decimais em um input de 'quantidade' dependendo de qual será o valor de um outro input chamado 'unidade'

Caso o input de unidade seja = 'L', só poderia ser permitido enviar no campo de 'quantidade' valores com 2 casas decimais, e caso o input seja 'CX' ou 'UN', só deveria ser permitido números inteiros.

Não sei como consigo pegar o 'value' do campo de 'Unidade' e como designar que o campo 'Quantidade' só pode ser inteiro ou com 2 casas decimais... Estava tentando utilizar do atributo 'step' mas também não consegui resolver...

Segue meus dois inputs:

```
<input
   onChange={handleInputChange}
   value={quantidade || ''}
   step={quantidadeValue}
   type="number"
   name="quantidade"
   id="quantidade"
   required />
<label htmlFor="quantidade"">
   Quantidade
</label>
```

```
<label htmlFor="unidade">Selecione uma opção</label>
<select
   onChange={handleInputChange}
   value={unidade || ''}
   name='unidade'
   id="unidade">
      <option selected>Unidade</option>
      <option value="UN">UN</option>
      <option value="L">L</option>
      <option value="CX">CX</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

No `handleInputChange` cujo o qual você não informou o que tem e é importante que você poste um exemplo de código completo, você pode editar o valor do campo para substituir ou formatar a resposta dela conforme o que houver no valor da variavel `unidade`.

O mais estranho para mim nesse código é que o onChange dos 2 componentes estão usando a mesma função, sendo que elas deveriam ser diferentes.

No `onChange` do componente de unidade você pode deixar padrão, mas o `onChange` do componente de quantidade você precisa fazer uma função para lidar com o valor inserido.